# Speed up numpy conditional replacement

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to speed up the inner most loop:

```
import cv2
import datetime
gt = cv2.imread("image.png",0)

start = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(gt.shape[0]):
    for j in range(gt.shape[1]):
        if(gt[i,j] == 0): continue
        limit = min(60,((gt.shape[1]-j)))
        for d in range(limit): # <------- this one
            if(gt[i,j] < gt[i,j+d] - d):
                gt[i,j] = 0
                break
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

Is there any way using numpy built-in operators to rewrite it? at the moment it is very slow, like 46 secs for each image. I already tried something like:

```
gt[ gt[i,j+range(d)] - range(d)]=0
```

but of course it doesn't work since you can't sum int with list.

Comment: Have you tried `np.where()`?

Comment: it isn't powerful enough, at least to my knowledge the condition can't be arranged to use lists

Comment: Why do you have a `break` inside the loop? Are you setting only the first element that satisfies the condition to zero???

Comment: Also, your condition will NEVER be satisfied for `d == 0`, so it is safe to use `range(1, limit)`.

Comment: The way your code is written, `gt[i,j+d]` will inevitably be out of range for any `d>0`. I think you should seriously revisit your code.

Comment: Please provide an example array.

Comment: @Alex you can try with any .png file. The smaller the better.

Comment: As noted by @AGNGazer your code goes out of bounds. An example array with expected output and current output is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ds can be represented with a constant `np.arange(60)` array, and the `gt[i,j+d]` with `gt[i, j:j+d]`.

```
import numpy as np
ds = np.arange(60)
for i in range(gt.shape[0]):
    for j in range(gt.shape[1]):
        if(gt[i, j] == 0):
            continue
        limit = min(60, ((gt.shape[1]-j)))
        if np.any(gt[i, j] < (gt[i, j:j+limit]-ds[:limit])):
            gt[i, j] = 0
```

If you don't have memory concerns, this can probably be vectorized further. For instance:

```
mask = np.zeros(gt.shape, dtype="bool")
for dist in range(1, 60):
    diffs = gt[:, :-dist] < (gt[:, dist:] - dist)
    mask[:, :-dist] |= diffs
gt[mask] = 0
```

When working with unsigned ints `diffs` should be calculated with:

```
diffs = (gt2[:, :-dist] < (gt2[:, dist:] - dist)) & (gt2[:, dist:]>dist)
```

to prevent overflow issues.

Which gives approx. 200x speedup on a 200x200pix image.

Comment: ~200x speedup compared to your first solution. Compared to the OP solution it's a ~5000x speedup.

Comment: Anyway the output for your second solution is not the same as the first.

Comment: @user32185 sorry, there was an indexing bug. Should be fixed now

Comment: I still don't get OP's intended behavior

Comment: @Alex It reproduces OP's code on my test cases. Do you have a failing example?

Comment: @kuppern87 Added example to my answer. Your code yields a different answer than the one it looks like OP intends. Thought to be fair OP's desired results are super ambiguous.

Comment: thank you, i completely forget about : operator in the bracket

Comment: just a small warning (maybe you can add it to the answer): Second solution does not work with unsigned int (which is the case when using opencv)

Comment: @Luca thanks for the heads up. Added a solution now using numpy. But probably better to use cv.subtract

Answer (score 0):

```
gt = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1.5, 2.5, 2.5], [2, 3.5, 4]])
limit = 2

m = np.zeros_like(gt, dtype=bool)
for d in range(1, limit + 1):
    if d >= gt.shape[0]:
        break
    shifted = np.roll(gt, shift=-d, axis=0)
    shifted[-d:] = np.nan
    m = m | (gt < shifted - d)
gt[m] = 0

print(gt)
```

outputs

```
array([[1. , 0. , 0. ],
       [1.5, 2.5, 0. ],
       [2. , 3.5, 4. ]])
```

Comment: Even your answer does not reproduce OP answer. It is difficult to reproduce an incorrect code, though.

Comment: @AGNGazer yeah OP's answer was wrong, but this looks like the intended logic... Added example.